# How does subtraction operator trigger an array-to-number conversion?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, numbers

Here are 2 examples of my code. The first one is:

```
console.log([4] + 10); //"410"
```

As far as I know, addition operator can work only with numbers and strings. So, firstly, `[4]` should be transformed into the number or string. When trying to convert an operand to a primitive data type, either `valueOf()` or `toString()` runs. By default, `valueOf()` returns an array, so this method is ignored. `toString()` is invoked. It converts the complex data type to a string. That's completely understandable for me, but...

What's going on in the second example?

```
console.log(10 - [4]); //6
```

**I don't get how `valueOf()` can transform array into the number if this method by default returns an array. What does occur here?**

Comment: See [ToPrimitive](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-toprimitive). With numeric hint, first `Symbol.toPrimitive` is tried, then `valueOf`, then `toString`. Follow along with [ApplyStringOrNumericBinaryOperator](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-applystringornumericbinaryoperator). `ToNumeric` calls `ToPrimitive` (which results in a string), but then `ToNumber` is called after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It goes this way:

```
10 - [4]
10 - '4' // array to string
10 - 4   // implicit casting of all operands to number with minus operator
6        // result
```

Comment: _“array to string”_ — More generally: object to primitive (with numeric hint, but for arrays `toString` is ended up being used by default). Specification: [ApplyStringOrNumericBinaryOperator](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-applystringornumericbinaryoperator).